# Why is the variable empty when using MailMessage

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    MailMessage mmSendEmail = new MailMessage();
    mmSendEmail.To.Add("abc@xyz.com");
    mmSendEmail.From = new MailAddress("abc@xyz.com");
    mmSendEmail.Subject = "Task#: " + s; //'s' is a query string from the URL of the page
    mmSendEmail.Body = "task ID: " + s + ".<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID='" + s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
    mmSendEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient scSend = new SmtpClient("mymailserverip");
    scSend.Send(mmSendEmail);
}
```

I receive the following email from the above code:

```
Subject: Task #: 0908090
Body: task ID: 0908090 <a href="http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID=">task</a>
```

How come the ID is missing from the link but shows up in other place.

Comment: shouldn't it be:
<a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID="+ s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
so without the single quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try String Format for that:

```
String.Format("task ID: {0}.<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID={0}' title='override'>task</a>",s)
```

Comment: Note you still have an extra `'` in `ID='{0}`

Comment: Thanks James, just fixed. it

Comment: great, but now you're missing one after `ID={0}` :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that your other attribute is missing too - you have a misplaced quote:

```
mmSendEmail.Body = "task ID: " + s + ".<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID='" + s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
                                                                                            ^
```

The highlighted quote should not be there, it should just be:

```
mmSendEmail.Body = "task ID: " + s + ".<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID=" + s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
```

A better solution would be to use `String.Format` as it cuts down on start/stop of the various quotes and makes issues like this easy to spot:

```
mmSendEmail.Body = String.Format("task ID: {0}.<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID={0}' title='override'>task</a>", s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the ' should be deleted:

```
mmSendEmail.Body = "task ID: " + s + ".<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID='" + s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
```

should be:

```
mmSendEmail.Body = "task ID: " + s + ".<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID=" + s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
```

otherwise the link is rendered like:

```
<a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID='s' title='override'>task</a>
```

... and this is not a valid href ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the single quotes around the s in the querystring is ending your href.
So replace it with:

```
mmSendEmail.Body = "task ID: " + s + ".<br /><br /> <a href='http://mypage.com/page.aspx?ID=" + s +"' title='override'>task</a>";
```